# how do I pass an ID from the URL into a form_tag in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one action which will include the .id for a vendor class through link_to.

That action which is a modification of the new() for a different controller for Reviews needs to pass both the value of the ID from the URL and the session[:user_id] into the database.

- How can I grab the value of the vendor.id?  Is it possible to not pass it through the URL and place it in the flash instead?
- do I use a hidden value to pass the session[:user_id]?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can access it as `params[:id]` from the controller action?  If so, you should be able to access it as `params[:id]` in the View.  Ditto for `session[:user_id]`.

**Edit**: I think I may have misunderstood your question.  Are you asking about posting the id back through the form?  Or possibly not having the id in the url?

Comment: yes, I did have the ID passed to the new but it wasn't being passed through the form.  Should I just use a hidden value?  Seems like that's how people are suggesting...although that's not particularly RESTful...

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing parameters between controllers, you should usually pass it as a parameter.

```
<%= link_to "Link to other controller", other_path(@other, :some_param => param_value) %>
```

In the action you're linking to (here it's SHOW), you'll be able to access :some_param as params[:some_param].

From forms, go ahead and include a hidden field (as long as you're checking to see if it's valid later on, since a user could submit anything).

Either way, don't use the flash to store session state - the flash is for user messages only.

Comment: If there is a has_many relationship (e.g. vendor has_many reviews) can I still use review_path and then pass vendor_id => @vendor.id?

Comment: I have it link to controller new which takes them to a submit form which I guess then upon submission calls create, and I get an error:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Vendor without an ID):

It seems like it is losing the ID when going from new to create?